# How to transform a string into a list of char and int using a list comprehension in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Given the following string:

```
"[10,20]"
```

I want to create the following list using a list comprehension in Python:

```
['[', 10, ',', 20, ']']
```

Being 10 and 20 **integers** and the rest of the elements in the list **chars**.

I assume that I would need a to use something similar to what [`itertools.groupby(iterable, key=None)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) provides:

> Make an iterator that returns consecutive keys and groups from the
> iterable. The key is a function computing a key value for each
> element. If not specified or is None, key defaults to an identity
> function and returns the element unchanged. Generally, the iterable
> needs to already be sorted on the same key function.

However Python's *group by* returns an iterator with consecutive *keys* and *groups*. In my case the keys would change so I guess I'd need a similar iterator that returns the groups based on a *filter*. Any ideas?

Comment: is the input always in a list of integers format? (`[5,6,7,8,10,401]`)

Comment: Yes, it is, but they're always in pairs and one pair could be another list:  `"[10,[20,30]]"`

Comment: so in that case you would need `['[',10,',','[',20,',',30,']',']']`?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this, what is your end goal?

Comment: I'm solving a series of problems on https://adventofcode.com/ to learn python.

Comment: For which of the problems is this?

Comment: [Day 18](https://adventofcode.com/2021/day/18)

Comment: @fvdalcin Hmm, then why do you want `['[', 10, ',', 20, ']']` instead of `[10, 20]`? Wouldn't that simple list of two numbers be much nicer and easier to work with? And it's much easier to get as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by whether this character is numeric or not. This can be done using the `str.isnumeric` function as the `key` argument to `groupby()`.

```
s = "[10,20]"
g = itertools.groupby(s, key=str.isnumeric)
```

Then, for the `True` groups, convert it to an integer. Leave `False` groups as-is.
Since the values of the `groupby` are iterators where each element is a separate character, you need to join it with `""` to convert it into a single string, and optionally convert that string to an integer.

```
lst = [int("".join(chars)) if is_numeric else "".join(chars) for is_numeric, chars in g]
```

Which gives:

```
['[', 10, ',', 20, ']']
```

In one line:

```
lst = [                  int("".join(chars)) 
      if is_numeric else "".join(chars) 
      for is_numeric, chars in itertools.groupby(s, key=str.isnumeric)
      ]
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done with regex with ease.

```
import re

NUMCHR = re.compile(r'\d+|[^\d]') #consecutive digits OR one "not-a-digit"
data   = '[10,20]'
out    = [int(m[0]) if m[0].isdigit() else m[0] for m in NUMCHR.finditer(data)]

print(out) #['[', 10, ',', 20, ']']
```

`.finditer` (in this case) will return either consecutive numbers or only 1 character on each iteration. We just check the return and proceed accordingly.

Comment: With even more ease: [`[m[1] or int(m[0]) for m in ...]`](https://tio.run/##JY49D4IwFEX3/ooXHEojEMDFxUkHFzUhcSodCC3axH6kPExM/O9YcLvn5ubk@g8@nd3tfZhnbbwLCEERcr1fjucGDhGK3hmvXyoNtJXbb9qeGGWw6Z0dVT@hfiuQ@qFxhFsDzipIrMO8y9cyIbLDDiCaKK/KrC4FJW5CWCtueCXABdAWU8NLwWCIZCLD/0ExaCs1qpAuHiYI8WEZR0X8wCmnGUQt0CyGegmCinn@AQ).

Comment: @KellyBundy that does not work. There isn't a group 1 so there is no m[1].

Comment: It's a link for a reason...

Comment: @KellyBundy :D, I see. I like it.

Comment: Heh, thanks to using `\D`, my regex even is shorter despite the extra parentheses :-)

Comment: @KellyBundy - Thanks for posting this. I never realized there was a "not-a-character" escape key. However, I am more impressed with your "absence of headlights" approach to determining if there are digits. Clever.

Comment: I'd say it's a variation of [The Greatest Regex Trick Ever](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html) or at least I might've been inspired by reading that a while back. Btw it would be good if you could include it in the answer (unless you don't want to).

Answer (score 1):

Use str.isdigit as your grouping key and convert groups that have a key of True to integers:

```
from itertools import groupby

s = "[10,20]"

r = [[str,int][k]("".join(g)) for k,g in groupby(s,key=str.isdigit)]

print(r)
['[', 10, ',', 20, ']']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `reduce` from functools:

```
from functools import reduce
def fun(x, y):
    if isinstance(x[-1], str) and x[-1].isdigit():
        x[-1] = x[-1] + y if y.isdigit()  else int(x[-1])
    else:
        x += [y]      
    return x

reduce(fun, '[10,[20,30]]', [''])[1:]
Out[]: ['[', 10, '[', 20, 30, ']']
```

Another approach may be to use recursion:

```
def fun_recurse(y, x=None):     
    if x is None:
        x = ['']
    if len(y) == 1:
        return x[1:] + [y]
    if isinstance(x[-1], str) and x[-1].isdigit():
       x[-1] = x[-1] + y[0] if y[0].isdigit() else int(x[-1])
       return fun_recurse(y[1:], x)
    else:
        return fun_recurse(y[1:], x + [y[0]])

fun_recurse('[10,[20,30]]')
Out[]: ['[', 10, '[', 20, 30, ']']
```

Comment: Maybe if you hadn't made it so complicated, you would've noticed your bug :-P Try input `'[1]'`.

Comment: Btw the output you show for your first one isn't truly what that produces.

Comment: @KellyBundy just noticed that its missing the last closing bracket